# Classifying TopoDS_Face face

Tags: opencascade

I have a `TopoDS_Face` object which comes from a translation of an IGES file. If I parse the IGES file using my own algorithm (written in C) which search for the faces then the loop(s) pointed to by the face and finally the edges in the loop, I can determine whether the face is planar or non-planar(semi-cylindrical in bends). This is done by checking if the edge is a line or an arc based on the form number in the underlying NURBS(entity 126). A line has form 1 and an arc has form 2.

What methods/functions or other mechanism can be used in Open Cascade to determine whether a `TopoDS_Face` is planar or semi-cylindrical(bends)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BRepAdaptor_Surface` class to get the type of `TopoDS_Face` surface:

```
BRepAdaptor_Surface surface = BRepAdaptor_Surface(face);
if (surface.GetType() == GeomAbs_Plane)
{
  // Surface is a plane
}
else
{
  // Surface is not a plane
}
```

**Update:**

The alternate way to define planar surface or not is using a curvature value. For planar surfaces a mean curvature should be equal to 0.

```
BRepAdaptor_Surface surface = BRepAdaptor_Surface(face);

double u = (surface.FirstUParameter() + surface.LastUParameter()) / 2.0;
double v = (surface.FirstVParameter() + surface.LastVParameter()) / 2.0;

BRepLProp_SLProps surfaceProps(surface, u, v, 2, gp::Resolution());
if (surfaceProps.MeanCurvature() == 0.0)
{
  // Surface is a plane
}
else
{
  // Surface is not a plane
}
```

Comment: Added a `cout` to print PLANAR or NON-PLANAR but the output is always NON-PLANAR where it should print PLANAR 12 times and NON-PLANAR twice.

Comment: It seems that in the CAD model is no information about surfaces types. In this case a surface curvature value can help. Look at the answer update.

Comment: `BRepLProp_SLProps surfaceProps(surface, u, v, 2, gp::Resolution());` there is no method called surfaceProps

Comment: That's true because `surfaceProps` is the object name. At this line a `BRepLProp_SLProps` constructor's called.